# Gzip / deflate not enabled accordin to Google pagespeed insights

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I am having this problem with google pagespeed insights, its complaining that the  content is not compressed. all JS, CSS and html.
I enabled Gzip on the server and .htaccess here is my htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

and here is what Google is complaining:
[pagespeed insights screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPA8W.png)

So I have tried everything, and cant see any progression :X

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed!
Nimbus hosting (plesk powered) has this Smart static files processing that was ticked one and somehow ignoring my htaccess for static file sering. So answer was to turn it off.

```
Smart static files processing : 
If turned off, Apache will process all requests for static files. nginx will only pass requests and responses without modification. Turn off this option only for troubleshooting.
```